# Instantiate a texture in the Unreal Editor

Tags: unreal-development-kit

I'm trying to create a vehicle which throws a ball (or, say, a spherical projectile) when clicking. I already have this vehicle doing the right thing, but I'd like it to throw a yellow-colored ball. I created a yellow texture but I don't know how to apply it specifically to the projectile.
I have to run the map on Unreal Tournament 3, so I may not be able to use the Unreal Development Kit.

Do you have some clues or an idea on how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to plug your Texture into a Material and assign that Material to your projectile mesh. You can do that in the editor, or you can override the mesh's materials in code inside the the mesh component by adding entries to the Materials array, e.g.:

```
Begin Object Class=StaticMeshComponent (or SkeletalMeshComponent) Name=ProjMeshComp
    StaticMesh=<your mesh>
    Materials(0)=<the material you created>
End Object
```

Comment: However I don't know how to assign this material to the projectile mesh because this mesh doesn't appear in the editor (it seems to be bound to the vehicle and appears only when I click, I don't know how to access it).

Comment: In your vehicle's defaultproperties, where the driver seat is set up it should declare a `GunClass`. If you open that weapon class and look at its defaultproperties, you will likely find an entry for `WeaponProjectiles`. If you open that projectile class, you should find what projectile is using for rendering. It looks like UT projectiles typically use particle systems, so you would probably have to find that particle system in the editor and open it up to figure out what mesh is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Is the projectile you are shooting a custom projectile?

If it is, look in your projectile class for a particle system component or a static mesh component reference similar to the answer Phillip posted. You will see something like:

```
ParticleSystem'SomePackage.SomeGroup.AssetName'
//or
StaticMesh'SomePackage.SomeGroup.AssetName'
```

The GroupName might not be present.

Then open up your editor and in your content browser find the package (in this case `SomePackage`). Right click it and be sure to Fully Load it. Now you should see your ParticleSystem or Static Mesh. If its a particle system, you need to edit the mesh module of the particle in cascade to use your material; otherwise you just reassign the static mesh material as usual.

If its not a custom projectile, you need to figure out which projectile class you are using and then do the above; a good starting place is the UTProjectile hierarchy of code.